# OpenAM Apache Web Agent Multiple Virtual host

Tags: apache, openam

We have successfully configured openam Apache web agent for one of the sites.

Now this is a development server and we have one apache serving multiple sites.
We configured one more virtual host in apache, which does not require openam authentication. But since openam agent is installed, if we try to access the second virtual host, apache redirects to the fqdn which requires openam.

We have made sure fqdn.check.enabled property is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the newer OpenAM 4.0 Apache agent - which supports virtual hosts. Previous agents do not support this feature.

Comment: OpenAM 4.0 agent gives error while installation while the earlier version(3.0.3) did not. The newer version tries to validate the configuration at the time of installation which the earlier version didnt do. It is failing when it is trying to send_session_request. This it did not try to do with earlier version at the time of installation

Answer (score 0):

You should add the unprotected virtual host to the agent profile as a not enforced URI.

Comment: We have added couple of URLs as non-enforced and inverted them, so that login page is only shown if those urls are accessed. So I think I dont have option to add unprotected virtual host to not enforced uri.